# Disable status 201 for all POSTs in NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

My client expects all successful status codes to equal 200. However NestJS uses 201 by default for all POST methods. How do I disable 201 for POSTs application wide? Not for one method but for the entire app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make an interceptor. But tbh, what's so bad about 201?

```js
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class PostStatusInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler) {
    const ctx = context.switchToHttp();
    const req = ctx.getRequest();
    const res = ctx.getResponse();
    return next.handle().pipe(
      map(value => {
        if (req.method === 'POST') {
          if (res.statusCode === HttpStatus.CREATED) {
            res.status(HttpStatus.OK);
          }
        }
        return value;
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

Comment: In actuallity I was fine with 201. But I am worried that my client might not understand it. So I wanted to make sure I can disable it if it will not work. The client is yet to be written and I don't know what to expect from their devs. It feels risky.

Comment: I usually tell the front end guys "You get what you're given" X'D they always want "All the things" and never want to implement pagination. To which I say "I've implemented pagination for a reason. Use it"

Comment: response.status is read-only. it can not be changed.

Comment: the fastest way to change the status is:  context.switchToHttp().getResponse().status(HttpStatus.OK);

Answer (score 28):

You should specify status codes for every controller

According official docs https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#status-code

> Furthermore, the response's status code is always 200 by default,
>   except for POST requests which use 201. We can easily change this
>   behavior by adding the @HttpCode(...) decorator at a handler-level
>   ([see Status codes](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#status-code)).

```
@Post()
@HttpCode(200)
create() {
  return 'This action adds data';
}
```

Also nestjs has another way which depends on library (express/fastify):

> We can use the library-specific (e.g., Express) response object, which
>   can be injected using the @Res() decorator in the method handler
>   signature (e.g., findAll(@Res() response)). With this approach, you
>   have the ability (and the responsibility), to use the native response
>   handling methods exposed by that object. For example, with Express,
>   you can construct responses using code like
>   response.status(200).send()

**But if it's possible I recommend to use [Reponse.ok](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok) to indetify success Response on the client side**

Comment: I already know how to do that for every method. I asked a global solution. It was articulated in the question.

Comment: You have no problem in backend part. it's about client side so I wrote about it. If you want to write bad code welcome

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `HttpCode()` decorator for each post to change it's return code.

The other option I can immediately think of would be to use an interceptor and modify the response status so long as it makes it to the interceptor, in the `pipe` method of the observable.

Comment: Why are you ignoring the question? It clearly says "Not for one method but for the entire app."

Comment: I didn't ignore the question. The second half of my response tells you exactly what to do in the case of using an interceptor. Even in Express, which nest is built on, you have to explicitly set the status to 200 instead of 201

Answer (score 2):

Interceptor approach worked for my CORS issue but I resented having the read through the documentation. Here's what and where it worked for me.

> **src/interceptors/post.interceptor.ts**

```
import {
  CallHandler,
  ExecutionContext,
  HttpStatus,
  Injectable,
  NestInterceptor,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class PostInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<Response>();

    if (request.method === 'POST') {
       if (response.status === 201)
          context.switchToHttp().getResponse().status(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

> **src/app.module.ts**

```
....
@Module({
   ...
   providers: [{
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: PostInterceptor
 }]
}
```

Comment: That looks a bit aggressive though. I mean if an individual action chooses a specific status then it will be overwritten. Especially in case of 404 and other errors handling but also possible redirects and so on.

Comment: @Gherman, true, you can add a check to only do this for status 201. Updated*

Comment: In my case, I use express, so `response.statusCode === 201` works instead of `response.status === 201`.

Comment: In this way all post will be changed in 201, also real create entity. So I don't suggest and I think that it is better and having more control with decorator